# How to facebook getuser() after login with javascript SDK

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, authentication, permissions

So I have to ask for extended permission by clicking the enter button, but after the login is necessary to refresh the page in order to display the app. Here's my code:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '< THE APPID >',
  'secret' => '< THE SECRET >',
  'cookie' => true,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
?>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

    FB.init({
      appId      : '< THE APPID >',
      status     : true,
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    $('#btn-enter').click(function(){
        login();
    });

  };
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {        
                // connected
            } else {
                // cancelled
            }
        //});
        }, {scope: 'read_friendlists,friends_photos,publish_stream'});
    }
</script>
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <!--Here is my APP-->
<?php else: ?>
<a id="btn-enter">Enter</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Is there a better way to do this ? What works for me is:

```
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            top.location.href='https://the_app_url';            
        } else {
        }
    //});
    }, {scope: 'read_friendlists,friends_photos,publish_stream'});
}
```

But this causes the entire page to refresh and is not 'elegant' per se...

Comment: If you want to react server-side (output different content) to the client-side login – then of course a reload is necessary. Or at least another HTTP request to the server – could also be AJAX for dynamically loading new content. But without a new request, the server does not know of anything that has happened client-side.

Answer (score 0):

After the user authentication, you can call the graph API by the Javascript SDK and issue a request to `/me`.

The response will contain an object with the user's info.

Here's how:

```
if (response.authResponse) {
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        alert(response.name);
   });  
}
```

Read more about it in the [Facebook Developers site](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.api/).

Comment: I don't need the user's info, but their friends info. that's why I need extended permission. What was bothering me was the need to refresh the page after logging in, but I found the problem:
I can use window.location.href = window.location.href; in the login function, but the trick is to remove the 'cookie="true"' from the facebook object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 require_once("facebook.php");
 $fbconfig['appid' ]     = "APPID";
 $fbconfig['secret']     = "SECRET";
 $fbconfig['baseurl']    = "BASEURL"; 
 $user            =   null; //facebook user uid
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
 )); 
 //Facebook Authentication part
    $user       = $facebook->getUser();
    //Login URL
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope'         => 'email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_work_history,user_about_me,user_hometown',
                'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
            )
    );
    //Logout URL
    $logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    if ($user){
        //get user basic description
        try {
          // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
          $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
          $_SESSION['fbid'] = $user_profile['id'];
          $_SESSION['logout'] = $logoutUrl;
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          //you should use error_log($e); instead of printing the info on browser
          d($e);  // d is a debug function defined at the end of this file
          $user = null;
        }
    }
$me = $user_profile;
//print_r($me);
//////////////////////////INSERTING DATA ON USER-RECORD FOR FACEBOOK USER/////////////////
if($_SESSION['fbid']){ 
$find_dup=$jeob->SqlQuery("select * from je_user_record where personal_id='".$me['id']."' AND first_name='".$me['first_name']."' AND last_name='".$me['last_name']."' AND email='".$me['email']."' AND oauth_provider='face' ");
//If no record in database
if($jeob->SqlRows($find_dup)=="0")
{
$insquery=mysql_query("insert into je_user_record (personal_id,first_name,last_name,email,oauth_provider) values('".$me['id']."','".$me['first_name']."','".$me['last_name']."','".$me['email']."','face')");
$faceuserid=mysql_insert_id();
    $_SESSION['userid'] =$faceuserid;
    $_SESSION['oauth_provider']= 'face';
//    header("location:index.php");
}
//if record found in database
//////////IF  RECORD FOUND IN DB//////////////////
else
{
    while($ff=mysql_fetch_array($find_dup))
    {
        $_SESSION['userid']=$ff['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['oauth_provider']= 'face';
    }
}

//Insert friend's ID on DB

        $fql    =   "SELECT uid,name,username,email,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
            $param  =   array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => $fql,
            'callback'  => ''
            );
            $friend_list   =   $facebook->api($param);
            /*$i=1;*/
            foreach($friend_list as $rec)
            {
            $frnname = $rec['name'];
            $frnid = $rec['uid'];
            $referid = $me['id'];
        $insert_table="fb_friends";
            $query=$jeob->SqlQuery("select * from ".$jeob->dbprefix.$insert_table." where refer_id='$referid' AND friends_id='$frnid' "); 
            if($jeob->SqlRows($query)=="0")
            {
                $insert_qry=array(
                "friends_id"=>"$frnid",
                "friend_name"=>"$frnname",
                "refer_id"=>"$referid");
                $jeob->SqlInsert($insert_table,$insert_qry);
            }
            else                    
            {                       //  if no record
            }                     
        }

} // end facebook session 
?>
```

In the above code after facebook user authentication their friends information is accessed and inserted into db. I think this may helps you. This code also clear the problem of refreshing the page after login with facebook